# Nashorn Javascript and ES6

Tags: javascript, jvm, nashorn

Is there a standalone build of the Nashorn JS engine that supports ES6 (by standalone, I mean usable with Java 8 as opposed to having to use a Java 9 preview or something)?

Comment: It is not supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for nashorn binary generated from jdk9 openjdk source that is runnable on jdk 8u? No, that is not possible. The source won't even compile with jdk8u.